# Selenium: Python script can't find 'service' argument

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've a Python script which I combine with the [selenium-webdriver](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/) to crawl a certain website and extract the content of a class. After that I save the result inside a MySQL database.

The file (automation.py) is located in the server directory /www/htdocs/xxx/wow/test:

```
import mysql.connector
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
host="xy.com",
user="dddddd",
password="xxxxxxx",
database="xxxxx"
)

service_object = Service('./chromedriver')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service_object)

driver.get('https://www.xxxxxx.com/')

sleep(5)

article_element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'line-name ')

article_text = article_element.text

sql = "REPLACE INTO dfbase (name) VALUES (%s)"
val = [(article_text)]
cursor = mydb.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql, val)
print("Inserted",cursor.rowcount,"row(s) of data.")
mydb.commit()
mydb.close()

driver.quit()
```

On my local environment the script is working as expected, but when I use it on my webserver I get the following error:

```
ssh-xxxx@xxxx:/www/htdocs/xxx/wow/test$ python automation.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "automation.py", line 19, in <module>
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service_object)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service'
```

Outout of "pip list":

```
ssh-xxxx@xxxx:/www/htdocs/xxx/wow/test$ pip list
Package                Version
---------------------- --------
apparmor               2.12
beautifulsoup4         4.6.0
bs4                    0.0.1
certifi                2023.5.7
charset-normalizer     2.0.12
chromedriver-installer 0.0.6
idna                   3.4
LibAppArmor            2.12
lxml                   4.9.2
matplotlib             2.1.1
numpy                  1.13.3
pexpect                4.2.1
pip                    21.3.1
python-dotenv          0.20.0
requests               2.27.1
selenium               3.141.0
setuptools             59.6.0
urllib3                1.26.16
webdriver-manager      3.7.1
wheel                  0.37.1
```

Comment: I don't believe `npm` packages would matter for Python.  Those are for Javascript.

Comment: Use `pip list` to show Python packages.

Comment: @JohnGordon I've edited a second screenshot with "pip list".

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Just include the output of `pip list` in the question, formatted as a code sample.

Comment: @larsks Alright I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your web server is using a very old version of `selenium` (`3.141.0`). The `service` arg doesn't exist there: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/selenium-3.141.0/py/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py#L33

You may want to compare `pip list` between your local environment and your server environment, as you are likely using `selenium` `4` on your local environment, which is why `service` exists there: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/selenium-4.10.0/py/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py#L32